# IE proxy settings not working for standard users

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-explorer, lan, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue we have a computer specifically setup for taking x rays

The computer has a proxy setting in connections > lan settings in internet options.

When I login in my admin account, the proxy settings take effect. I can access the specific sites allowed

When I login as my standard account, the proxy settings DO NOT take effect. I CANNOT access the specific sites allowed

I did a reset of IE, and reinstalled IE, but did not help

I also tried opening IE (without addons)

I even logged in as standard user then opened IE as admin, same behavior is in Chrome

in admin = works

in standard = does not work

I restarted the computer

Is it a registry setting possibly?

Curious if anyone has ever encountered such an issue before.

and yes I did double check to make sure the proxy setting was applied and automatically detect is off